# How to make a circle grow?

Tags: java, swing, object, geometry, jcomponent

I am trying to make my circle grow. When it is created, i want it to start from a size, and disapear when it reaches a maximum size. My circle is supposed to represent some kind of explosion.

```
public class Circle extends JComponent {

private int size;
private int max = 500;

public Circle(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    setSize(500, 500);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.orange);
    g.fillOval(0, 0, size, size);
}}
```

So, as you can see, it is a very basic circle. And I just want to create that little animation.

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer` to adjust the `size` then call `repaint()`.  There are plenty of [examples around the site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing+timer) .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a matter well covered in the official tutorial, in [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making a class for the explosion to store its position and current size across render frames.
To grow the circle simply subtract how much you want it to grow (in pixels) from its position, this will give the x and y coordinates for the fillOval, the width and height arguments will be the size. e.g

`g.drawOval(x - radius, y - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius );`

You can then pair this with a condition such as `radius > 100` to decide if the explosion has finished - then dont render it.